# How to match single Image with multiple images using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, matlab-cvst

For example I have a 100 images in my directory of which 'x' images are same and I would like to know the value of x.

Comment: The same as an exact copy?

Comment: @AnderBiguri
I mean I want to know the value of X. i.e., I would like to see all the pictures !!

Comment: What? All pictures =100 then x=100? the comment you made is incoherent with the question. Can you please explain in at leas 10 lines what your problem is?

Comment: @AnderBiguri
I'll explain you in detail now...Let us assume a Scenario I have a video clip of 10 min. In that I would like to know presence (total time) of a particular person in the video. 
For that I extracted all the frames in the video and now I wanted to match with the input image and then calculate the frames in terms of time eg. say 24fps...if 500 pictures are matching  500/24 Sec.

Comment: That describes better the problem, however, it describes a prbolem that can be solved with a team of 4 PhD students in 5 years, not something you can just ask Stackoverflow

Comment: @AnderBiguri
Could you Please help me out of this problem!! I took this as a challenging Project in my college!!

Comment: If you have the funding and 5 years.....

Comment: @KanakaRaju, use simple maths... You have 500 frames at 24 p/sec so `500 / 24 = 20 secs`. Person is at frame 195 for next 72 frames. So `195 / 24 = 8`. Now you know "No person on screen until 8 secs" then `72/24 = 3` so they're on screen for 3 seconds. Now `8 + 3 = 11` leaving next 9 seconds remaining, from 20, after person left camera's view. Read your **one sentence question** again and tell us how anyone was gunna tell you this from just that **one line**??. Right now, I myself can't even be sure if I've gave what you needed. Edit your question showing effort of what/where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% Reference image
img_ref = imread('img_ref.jpg');

% Create an variable for alloc the path
img_path ='/your/dir/of/images/'

% Create an variable struct, for searching files with .jpg extension 
names = dir(fullfile(img_path, '*.jpg'));

% Counts the number of images on the path
n_imgs = numel(names); 

for n = 1:n_imgs
    full_name = fullfile(img_path, names(n).name);
    your_imgs = imread(full_name);

    r = isMatch(img_ref,your_imgs);
    disp(r)
end
```

You can use the function created above by [Rob F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5946828/rob-f)

```
function[result] =  isMatch(RealImage, TestImage)

testImage = imread(TestImage);
if (sum(sum(sum(RealImage == testImage))) == size(RealImage,1) * size(RealImage,2) * size(RealImage,3))
    result = true;
else
    result = false;

end
```

Comment: Let us assume a Scenario I have a video clip of 10 min. In that I would like to know presence (total time) of a particular person in the video. 
For that I extracted all the frames in the video and now I wanted to match with the input image and then calculate the frames in terms of time eg. say 24fps...if 500 pictures are matching  500/24 Sec. Is there any other way to find?? 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: @KanakaRaju, Let's assume you learn to use to a calculator. You asked one thing and got useful answers for what you asked (500 images in a directory), now its like they wasted their (unpaid) time writing just so you can change the rules..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and that all you wish to do is count how many images are EXACTLY the same as some target image, then this should work...

```
%directory where images are stored
directory = 'Directory_To_Images';
files = dir(directory);

%total number of matches
numMatches = 0;

%The Real image, the image you wish to test against
RealImage = imread('Target_Image.jpg');

%go through all files in the directory
for i = 1 :  length(files)
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(files(i).name);

%test to make sure its a JPG image (you may need to modify this if you have
%multiple file types
if (strcmp(ext,'.jpg'))
    %check if the images match
    if(isMatch(RealImage, [directory '\' name ext]))
        numMatches = numMatches+1;
    end
end
end

sprintf('Number of matches: %s', num2str(numMatches))
```

Here is the missing function:

```
function[result] =  isMatch(RealImage, TestImage)

testImage = imread(TestImage);
if (sum(sum(sum(RealImage == testImage))) == size(RealImage,1) * size(RealImage,2) * size(RealImage,3))
    result = true;
else
    result = false;

end
```

Comment: Let us assume a Scenario I have a video clip of 10 min. In that I would like to know presence (total time) of a particular person in the video. For that I extracted all the frames in the video and now I wanted to match with the input image and then calculate the frames in terms of time eg. say 24fps...if 500 pictures are matching 500/24 Sec. Is there any other way to find?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @KanakaRaju, Let's assume you learn to use to a calculator. You asked one thing and got useful answers for what you asked (500 images in a directory), now its like they wasted their (unpaid) time writing just so you can change the rules..